# Having trouble creating a virtualenv in Visual Studio

Tags: python, flask, cmd, virtualenv

This might be a very basic problem but I can't seem to be able to install and name a virtualenv in VisualStudio.

Once I open up the terminal I enter
`pip3 install virtualenv`.
It then says it's been successfully installed but when I enter `virtualenv env`
it shows an error in the terminal stating `The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try  again.`

So far I have tried uninstalling and installing the virtualenv but that hasn't seemed to work. I suspect that it might be an issue of the path but I'm not sure how to solve it. I have been trying to follow the first 5 minutes of this flask tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA

Answer (score 0):

Try running `python3.9 -m virtualenv env`. The error you are getting is because of issues with your path. (You can fix them but it's not mandatory, google "add python virtualenv to path" if you want)